# Processing ~12 millions coordinates and checking if they fall in a geojson polygon

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, numpy, amazon-ec2

I have a file which contains around 12 million coordinates. For each coordinate I have to check which polygon it falls under. There are around 15000 polygons in the GeoJSON file.

Processing a 1000 rows takes ~7 mins on a memory optimized r4.8xlarge EC2 instance which has around 244 Gb of memory. How can I optimize this?

```
# load GeoJSON 
with open('geodata.json') as f:
    js = json.load(f)

df = pd.read_csv('coordinates.csv', usecols=['long', 'lat'])

data = {}
for row in df.itertuples():
    if row[1].item() == 0.0:
        continue
    point = Point(row[1].item(), row[2].item())
    for feature in js['features']:
        polygon = shape(feature['geometry'])
        if polygon.contains(point):
            x = feature['properties']
            fid = x['FID']
            if not fid in data:
                data[fid] = 1
            else:
                data[fid] += 1
            break


# print data
print data
json.dump(data, file('data.txt', 'w'))
```

Comment: What’s `shape`?

Comment: Shape is from shapely library which takes all coordinates under the geometry field and makes a shape, which is hexagon in this case. @Ryan